# Raspberry Pi Camera Module.Check if connected

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, pi

I'm programming a small application in python for the raspberry pi 3. The application uses the camera module.

I want to check if the camera is connected to the raspberry pi. The only way i found so far of doing just that is like this:

```
from picamera import PiCamera
try:
    piCamera = PiCamera()
except Exception as e:
    print("camera is not conencted")
```

While this works. I don't like this because if the camera is connected i'm suddenly using its resources and creating a piCamera object where i might not need it.

So my question is. Is there any better way of doing this? Something that just checks if the camera is connected.

Comment: Try `/opt/vc/bin/vcgencmd get_camera`